# If my PHP file return true, my javascript should run

Tags: javascript, php, setinterval

I've set a 5ms Interval for my javascript to load my time.php file,
if my php returns true, my javascript should fire up my audio.

could anyone help me please? thanks a lot!.

**index.html**

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('time.php', function(data) {
        if(/*What should i put in here?*/){
            $('#Audio')[0].play();
        }else{
            //do nothing
        }
    }); 
},500);
```

**time.php**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE time=NOW()");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count>0){
    return true;
    exit();
}else{
    //do Nothing    
}
```

Comment: What if you echo true instead of return? Btw, the return true and exit() are redundant, return will stop the script.

Comment: Please edit this post to include a description of the problem you are having, and *what you have tried* in order to resolve that problem

Comment: `if(data == 1){`  and `return '1';` instead of `return true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

**time.php**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE time=NOW()");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count>0){
    echo '1';
    exit();
}
```

**index.html**

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('time.php', function(data) {
        if(data == '1'){
            $('#Audio')[0].play();
        }
    }); 
},500);
```

Comment: ha you posted while i was typing :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the ReferenceError in your code or misprint. Variable `check` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data` instead of `check`

```
if(data){
   $('#Audio')[0].play();
}else{
   //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**index.html**

```
setInterval(function(){
$.get('time.php', function(data) {

if(data == '1'){
    $('#Audio')[0].play();
}else{
    //do nothing
}
    }); 
},500);
```

**time.php**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE time=NOW()");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        if($count>0){
            exit('1');
        }else{
            exit('0');//let the script have something not 1
            //do Nothing    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't run the Php inside the interval.
Because you might not know how much **time** is required for **PHP to return the value**, if its a huge database.
Get value from PHP individually outside JavaScript and then enter setInterval-function().